# IIF Statement with and operator - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, iif

My IIF statement is giving an error, I need to check that 2 fields is not zero so that it does not give a division by zero error, please can someone help me:

```
=iif(isnumeric(sum(Fields!Month13.Value, "SKU")) and 
     isnumeric(sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU")),
(sum(Fields!Month13.Value, "SKU") - sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU")) / 
sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU"),
0)
```

Comment: just add `and sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU") > 0` to the first part of the IIF statement?

Comment: What are the datatypes of `Month1` and `Month13`? Do you expect any of the individual rows to *not* be numeric?

Answer (score 1):

That has to do with how SSRS evaluates the Iif statement.
To avoid errors you have to use two Iif statements

```html
=
IIF(Sum(Fields!Month1.Value)=0,0,Sum(Fields!Month13.Value) -Sum(Fields!Month1.Value))
/
IIF(Sum(Fields!Month1.Value)=0,1,Sum(Fields!Month1.Value))
```

Another option is using custom code functions like the one below

```html
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you wanted to handle this you could do

```
=iif(isnumeric(sum(Fields!Month13.Value, "SKU")) and 
 isnumeric(sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU")) and
 sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU") > 0,
(sum(Fields!Month13.Value, "SKU") - sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU")) / 
sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU"),
0)
```

or put another IIF statement within the IIF statement to check that the sum of month1 is more than 0 else give a 1.

```
=iif(isnumeric(sum(Fields!Month13.Value, "SKU")) and 
 isnumeric(sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU")),
(sum(Fields!Month13.Value, "SKU") - sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU")) / 
iif(sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU") > 0, sum(Fields!Month1.Value, "SKU"), 1)
0)
```

Answer (score -1):

OK so finally I used this:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Month13.Value) = 0, -1, 
iif(Sum(Fields!Month1.Value) = 0,1,
(Sum(Fields!Month13.Value) - Sum(Fields!Month1.Value)) / 
IIf(Sum(Fields!Month1.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!Month1.Value))))
```